# Why the signal pause will cause the program to sleep forever?

Tags: c, unix, signals

The APUE book says that: If the signal occurs after the test of `sig_int_flag` but before the call to `pause`, the process could go to sleep forever.

I don't know why, can somebody tells me?
Thanks a lot.

```
int sig_int();                 /* my signal handling function */
int sig_int_flag;              /* set nonzero when signal occurs */

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, sig_int)    /* establish handler */
    .
    .
    .
    while (sig_int_flag == 0)
        pause();               /* go to sleep, waiting for signal */
}

int sig_int() {
    signal(SIGINT, sig_int);   /* reestablish handler for next time */
    sig_int_flag = 1;          /* set flag for main loop to examine */
}
```

Comment: If the `while` condition is tested before a `SIGNT` had been handled the code runs in to UB, as `sig_int_flag` is read uninitialised.

Comment: "*...  go to sleep forever*" until the next `SIGINT` is handled.

Comment: @alk wouldn't it be zero because global? I'm not saying this is correct, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an interrupt signal is issued at the precise time you're describing:

- the flag has been checked false: entering loop
- signal resets itself, setting the flag to `1`, but too late (test has been done)
- since loop has already been entered, `pause()` is called and the program waits

That said, if CTRL+C/SIGINT is triggered another time, you can exit the loop, so it's not that critical, since that signal can be issued manually.

If you want to check that behaviour, I suggest you add a `sleep` statement:

```
while (sig_int_flag == 0)
{
     printf("Hit CTRL+C in the next 10 seconds to trigger the bug\n");
     sleep(10);
     pause();               /* go to sleep, waiting for signal */
}
```

A workaround would be to remove the `pause()` statement and replace it by a polling loop:

```
while (sig_int_flag == 0)
{
     sleep(1);
}
```

If a SIGINT occurs anywhere in the loop, including between the `while` and the `sleep`, then the worse thing that can happen is that the program waits 1 second before noticing that the flag is set, then it exits the loop, and the other, more plausible case it that the `sleep` call is interrupted, and the loop is exited immediately, so when the signal is set, there's little visible difference between that and a `pause` call if we only expect `SIGINT`.

Answer (score 0):

The question's already answered. However, additional answer can consolidate the idea.

```
while (sig_int_flag == 0) {
          <-----  think it signal is caught here before pause btw while and pause()
    pause();               /* go to sleep, waiting for signal */
}
```

Having caught, signal handler runs. After it finishes its task, it returns to a point at which the signal is caught, in `main()` in this case. So, the point is `pause()` and `pause()` is called. It waits again `SIGINT` to catch. To exemplify it, I add `sleep(5)` equivalently to catch prior `pause()`.

[image]

So, we typically want the second situation. To achieve it always, the aforementioned code block has to be *atomic*. That's why `sigsuspend()` is better and should be used.

If you would like to experience the fallible case,

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t sig_int_flag = 0;    /* set nonzero when signal occurs */

char const * handlerMsg = "in handler\n";
int handlerMsgLen;


void sig_int(int s) {
    signal(SIGINT, sig_int);   /* reestablish handler for next time */
    sig_int_flag = 1;          /* set flag for main loop to examine */
    write(2, handlerMsg, handlerMsgLen);
}

void mySleep() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        sleep(1);
        fprintf(stderr, "%d ", i + 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    handlerMsgLen = strlen(handlerMsg);
    signal(SIGINT, sig_int);    /* establish handler */

    while (sig_int_flag == 0) {
        mySleep();
        pause();               /* go to sleep, waiting for signal */
    }
}
```